# Dexie.js index lost on reload

Tags: typescript, electron, dexie

I have an Electron app that uses [Dexie.js](http://dexie.org) on top of IndexedDb.  Following the instructions [here](http://dexie.org/docs/Typescript) for Typescript, I've subclassed Dexie and am defining my Db in my constructor:

```
super('myDb');
this.version(1).stores({
  myTable: 'testGuid, tag, downloadDate'
});
```

Everything works the first time.  The DB and table are created in IndexedDb and I can insert records.  Looking at IndexedDb through the "Application" tab of the Chrome DevTools, I can see the data in the table, and as listed in each index.

If I now simply reload the application (Ctrl-R in Electron), at least one of the indexes is blank and I start getting errors in the VSCode console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'keyPath' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'databaseId' of undefined
```

The data is still in the table - I can see it in the table view in the Application tab:
[image: Data in table]

But when I click on one of the indices in the table view, it is just blank:

[image: No data in index?]

I also just noticed that the Database listing seems to be stuck with both **Security Origin** and **Version** blank:

[image: Database Info]

I just ran another test and I don't actually even have to insert any records into the table to cause the problem.  Simply loading my app, which creates the DB/table, and then reloading Electron will cause an index to go wonky.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

- Dexie 2.0.4
- Electron 2.0.3
- Angular 6.0.1
- Typescript 2.7.2
- Node 8.9.4

**Update #1**

I don't even need to reload my app.  If I simply load the app, go into the Application tab and verify that the Db/table/indexes all exist and then refresh the Db from within the Application tab, at least one index is now broken/empty.

**Update #2**

I'm getting the same results using the sample code from the Dexie Typescript instructions.

Comment: Hi Tim, did you ever find a solution for this? I'm getting this issue after a hard reset (Dexie fails to delete a row which I can see sitting in the IndexedDB)